# Fatal Error Unable to attach to base address

Tags: symfony

When I try to do a composer update, it appears the following message: "Fatal Error Unable to attach to base address"
I'm using symfony 3

I hope you could help me. Thanks

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK7eE.png)

Comment: If you try `php composer update` does that make a difference?

Comment: Hi @Alvin, no. With php composer update, occures the same.

Comment: Looks like you are using xampp. Can you try stopping apache, and then do `composer update`? See if that makes a difference?

Comment: YES!!, you have resolved it. Thanks Alvin

Comment: Hi there Francisco - I posted my answer. Can you use the checkmark to mark it as the correct answer. That way when people search for the same question, they can find the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have xampp, do this:

1. Stop apache.
2. Run `composer update`

That should fix it!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that fixed this for us was to reboot our computer. Go figure!

Answer (score 0):

for example, in your appBundle/Controler/DefaultController

just remove arguments passed in array

from:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        ]);
    }
}
```

to:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
```

...all use statements

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [

        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to solve the error just stop your apache server and run **composer update** and again start the apache server and the error gone. i believe this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Run **composer update** and **restart the apache server**. It's working fine.

Comment: Please explain why the user needs to do this, it will help them understand your answer better.

Comment: Sometimes it shows the error message. For me, I just stopped the apache & run composer update. then again start the apache. after that, it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If merely running `composer update` doesn't solve your problem. Try below solution.

Add below entries at the beginning of your Apache 2.4's conf file.
SetEnv TEMP "C:\Temp\directory\path"
SetEnv TMP "C:\Temp\directory\path"

Restart apache/httpd service.